# redirect neo4j profiling output to file

Tags: cypher, profiling, cypher-shell

I am profiling a query with cypher-shell, since according to [this post](https://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-2-2-query-tuning/) it is easier to be compared.

My command is something like the following (the query is different).

```
sudo cypher-shell -a myip:myport -u myusr -p 'my_pwd' "EXPLAIN MATCH (t1:Node1{field:1})−[:rel1]−>
( : Node2 {ID :"01"})<−[:rel1]−(t2:Trip{Direction:0})
RETURN t1, t2 LIMIT 1;"
```

This command print the profiling of the query to Terminal. However, it is difficult to read on the Terminal so I was trying to redirect the output to file such as:

```
sudo cypher-shell -a myip:myport -u myusr -p 'my_pwd' "EXPLAIN MATCH (t1:Node1{field:1})−[:rel1]−>
( : Node2 {ID :"01"})<−[:rel1]−(t2:Node2{field:0})
RETURN t1, t2 LIMIT 1;" >> out.txt
```

However, the resulting file contains no profiling but only a couple of lines such as:

```
Plan: "EXPLAIN"
Statement: "READ_ONLY"
Version: "CYPHER 3.5"
Planner: "COST"
Runtime: "INTERPRETED"
Time: 0
```

How to redirect neo4j profiling output to file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `--format verbose` flag to the command.

```
sudo cypher-shell -a myip:myport -u myusr -p 'my_pwd' --format verbose "EXPLAIN MATCH (t1:Node1{field:1})−[:rel1]−>
( : Node2 {ID :"01"})<−[:rel1]−(t2:Node2{field:0})
RETURN t1, t2 LIMIT 1;" >> out.txt
```

`cypher-shell` seems to default to `--format plain` if output is being redirected to a file.

[Example output for a different query but the same command as above - not sure it's that much more readable](https://gist.github.com/Pablissimo/ad21c8d3501cc819396a7122a016ec1b)